# Vectorising Pandas - Assigning Column to Array Value using another Column

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a Pandas Dataframe with some values to match against location data. I want to use values from one of my columns to grab the location datafrom a 2d array, using the column data as an array index.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ExistingColumn': [0,2,3,1,2,3,0,0,2,3]})
```

```
df1['NewColumn'] = array[df1['ExistingColumn']][1]
```

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through rows manually?

FYI Array looks like this:

```
[['2_-34.0,140.95.kml', -34.0, -36.425, 143.575, 140.95], 
['2_-34.0,143.575.kml', -34.0, -36.425, 146.2, 143.575], 
['2_-36.425,140.95.kml', -36.425, -38.849999999999994, 143.575, 140.95], 
['2_-36.425,143.575.kml', -36.425, -38.849999999999994, 146.2, 143.575]]
```

I need to return the lat long coordinates to columns in Dataframe based on the values of 'ExistingColumn'.

Output I'm looking for:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ExistingColumn': [0,2,3,1,2],'NewColumn':[-34,-36.425,-36.425,-34,-36.425]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2d array is `arr` and same length like column use indexing:

```
arr = np.array([['2_-34.0,140.95.kml', -34.0, -36.425, 143.575, 140.95], 
['2_-34.0,143.575.kml', -34.0, -36.425, 146.2, 143.575], 
['2_-36.425,140.95.kml', -36.425, -38.849999999999994, 143.575, 140.95], 
['2_-36.425,143.575.kml', -36.425, -38.849999999999994, 146.2, 143.575]])


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ExistingColumn': [0,2,3,1,2,3,0,0,2,3]})

df1['NewColumn'] = arr[df1['ExistingColumn'], 1]
print (df1)
   ExistingColumn NewColumn
0               0     -34.0
1               2   -36.425
2               3   -36.425
3               1     -34.0
4               2   -36.425
5               3   -36.425
6               0     -34.0
7               0     -34.0
8               2   -36.425
9               3   -36.425
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use df1['ExistingColumn'] to specify which value to return from the array. Hence, ```array[df1['ExistingColumn']][1]```

Comment: ExistingColumn is a Pandas column with a million rows and values x = 0,1,2 or 3. Using each separate ExistingColumn value I need to return the corresponding array[x][1] value in a new column.